# How do i create a automatic find player script

Tags: lua, roblox

so I am learning Lua at the moment and wanted to make something that if the player presses f it would print something. I know how to use input service. but what I DO NOT KNOW is how get the server to automatically detect the player. so a combat game for example.
you join with controls already there . I'm really confused!

```
local player = game:getservice("players")
local input = game:GetService("UserInputService")
input.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.F then
    print("hi")
end
```

end)

Comment: Heyo, based on the title and your question, it's still unclear what you are trying to do. Are you having trouble detecting when a player joins the game? What do you mean by having "controls already there"? Do you want a GUI to appear for each player when they join? Or just controls?   Could you edit your question and add some more details to further explain what you are trying to do, include a code sample of what you've tried, and what isn't working?

Comment: @kylaaa i just edited it. could you please review it?

Comment: Take a look at the [Player.PlayerAdded signal](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/Players/PlayerAdded). There's a code example on how to detect when a player joins the game. But it's still unclear how that connects to what you are trying to do with detecting input. Do you want to make it so that UserInputService works as soon as a player joins the game?

Comment: Yea! thats what im trying to do " that UserInputService works as soon as a player joins the game"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to detect when a player joins to make your controls work. The problem is likely that your code is in a Script, and not a LocalScript. Scripts run on the server, and LocalScripts run on each individual client. Plus, user input needs to be detected on the client as well.

So, create a LocalScript in StarterPlayer > StarterCharacterScripts. This will replicate the code into each player when their Character spawns into the world. Then, move your existing code in there.

```
local uis = game:GetService("UserInputService")
uis.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.F then
        print("hi")
    end
end)
```

Comment: apparently  getservice is not a valid member of DataModel "Baseplate" ???????!

Comment: THANKS IT WORKED! but what I cant do is fetch the humanoid and set it to something. (for example I could subtract 10 health from the player from a  press of a button)

Comment: @therealweldtool, you should do some searching to see if there are any answers already on here for dealing damage to players. I'm not going to be adding anything more to this answer. If you are still stuck when it comes to locating a player, or dealing damage, you should ask a new question after you've tried to solve it yourself.